# How to recover corrupted PNG files due to improper .gitattributes?

Tags: git, png, gitattributes

I added & committed & pushed several PNG files into my git repo, but unfortunately, I had an improper .gitattributes file like this:

```
* text
# no settings for PNG files
```

The PNG files were treated as text files by git. Now I cannot open them anymore and I also lost the original copy of them. Is there any way to recover them? Thanks!

---

**Update**: The `.gitattributes` was already in the repo when the PNG files were added. That means I cannot find a *good* state for the PNG files in the commit history. And all commits were made on Windows.

Comment: It's a matter of line end characters, so you could try (without guarantee of success) to replace all occurrences of the LF char by CRLF (I imagine that if you have this problem it's because you use git on windows)

Comment: I don't think this can be done, because you'll need to somehow detect which LF were originally CRLF and which weren't. I don't know how you could do that in a compressed binary stream. I suppose the odds are only a few LF where originally CRLF (assuming that the distribution of characters preceding LF is pretty close to uniform in a compressed stream), so a repair tool could try each possible way of changing one LF, then each combination of two LFs, etc, but clearly this will be very expensive, and manual unless there's an automated way of detecting a valid fixed file.

Comment: Have you tried to put `text eol=crlf` in .gitattributes and [refresh your repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings)?

Comment: @DenizToprak Tried that, but still can't open. Maybe it's because I'm working on Mac. I don't have access to Windows right now.

Comment: @joanis I'm afraid you are right. The PNG files are relatively large (> 1MB). There will be too many LFs to try.

Comment: @Philippe Yes, the files were committed on Windows. Setting `* text` was a big mistake.

Answer (score 9):

Let's take a scenario where you have 2 commits:

- In the first one all PNG files are handled as binary, the files are sound.
- The second commit includes `.gitattributes` file and all the PNG files gets corrupted, as they are treated as text files.

Here is the `git log` output:

```
commit d075d282795362e03318d93c36406822facc015c (HEAD -> master)
Author: John Doe <john.doe@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 26 17:12:16 2019 +0100

    Bad state
    Gitattributed file added, PNG files are treated as text, they are now corrupted

commit fcaa5a87eb816ddafbd256e83ea4be004a87a6e8
Author: John Doe <john.doe@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 26 17:11:36 2019 +0100

    Good state
    PNG Files are treated as binary, they are not corrupted yet
```

First reset all PNG files to their initial state:

`git reset fcaa5a87eb816ddafbd256e83ea4be004a87a6e8 -- *.png`

Then commit the changes without adding any file:

`git commit -m 'Fix PNG files'`

Discards all changes from the working directory:

`git checkout '*.png'`

Finally remove erroneous `.gitattributes` entry or replace it with:

`*.png binary`

You can also use a [gitattributes template](https://github.com/alexkaratarakis/gitattributes/blob/master/Web.gitattributes) including many other file types.

---

### Update:

If there is no 'good' state, where the images were intact, you can try to fix the issue by manipulating the files. You need to add missing newline characters. You don't know the right positions since git has removed them all. From my experience, if you add just one carriage return at the end of the first line, it fixes most of the small PNG files. I don't know why and there is no guarantee but you can still try:

First remove all PNG files:

`rm -f *.png`

Then declare PNG files as binary in `.gitattributes`:

`*.png binary`

Restore the files:

`git checkout '*.png'`

Add a carriage return at the end of the first line:

`perl -i -p -e 's/$/$1\r/ if $. == 1;' *.png`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is not my scenario. In my case, the *bad* `.gitattributes` file was already there when the PNG files were added. That means there are no *good* state for the PNG files in the git commit history. Is this still solvable?

Comment: I found that this only works for small PNG files, in which the `0x0a0d` pattern only appears once. If there are multiple instances of `0x0a0d` pattern, the processed PNG file either cannot be opened correctly (or not at all).

Comment: The pattern should not occur that often, even in a big .png file. Have you tried looping over 1 to 10 or 20, and changing the `$. == 1` for each digit and seeing if it works? I suspect in most cases you'll have only one instance of 0x0a0d in the original file you're trying to recover. Afterall, assuming the uniform distribution that  compression tries to achieve, you should only have one instance of that pattern per 64kB. OK, that's not that big a file, maybe I'm overly optimistic about this approach...

Comment: @joanis As you commented before, I have to figure out which LFs were originally CRLFs. Even though the `0x0a0d` pattern appeared not so often in the original file, but I don't know that. All I have is the corrupted file, and every `0x0a` byte is a suspect.

Comment: Adding a `0x0a0d` at the end of the first line works apparently on small files but not on big ones. It seems there is no way to recover them. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Deniz thanks for the clarification. I was wondering how come it worked for you, but on small files the odds aren't that bad you'd be lucky, so I understand now. If I had a few days to kill, I'd find it fun to take up the challenge to write a recovery tool, but as Ben.W confirmed, it is a hard problem and I unfortunately don't have the time to work on it...

Comment: Just did some reading on the .png format. The magic number has both a Unix and a DOS line end, precisely to detect corruption via line end conversion. Your solution fixes the magic number, thus disabling that early corruption detection. Any file that didn't contain `0x0a0d` before being corrupted will be fixed by your solution, which explains why it works on most small png files. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

For small files it's easy, for files in the 60-200KB range it should still be feasible, for larger files it's hopeless.

**Zero or one random newline corrupted**

*Easy going.*

This brute force bash script, built on the Perl one-liner provided by @Deniz in his answer, worked on a file that had lost just one random newline after the one in the magic number:

```
lines=`wc -l < image.corrupted.png`
for x in `seq 1 $((lines+1))`; do 
   echo -n $x ''
   perl -pe 's/$/$1\r/ if ($. == 1 || $. =='$x')' < image.corrupted.png > image.fixed.png
   if pngcheck image.fixed.png; then
      echo Valid file substituting newline numbers 1 and $x
      break
   fi
done
```

The file was 97KB large, and this took about 11s.

**Two random newlines corrupted**

*Be patient.*

This should work with two random newlines missing plus the initial one:

```
lines=`wc -l < image.corrupted.png`
foundit=
for x in `seq 3 $((lines+1))`; do 
   date
   echo $x
   time for y in `seq 3 $((lines+1))`; do
      echo -n $y ''
      perl -pe 's/$/$1\r/ if ($. == 1 || $. =='$x' || $. =='$y')' < image.corrupted.png > image.fixed.png
      if pngcheck image.fixed.png; then
         echo Valid file substituting newline numbers 1, $x and $y
         foundit=1
         break
      fi
   done
   if [[ $foundit ]]; then
      break
   fi
done
```

It took 2 minutes to complete one iteration of the inner loop, and a day and a half to find the fixed image.

If your file is smaller than 200 KB, you might have some hope with this approach, if you're lucky enough that no more than 2 random newlines were corrupted, but from 3 random newlines on it's hopeless. Remember you expect an average of one random corrupted newline per 64 KB. So of course if you're not lucky, even a smaller file might have had more CRLFs.

**Three or more random newlines corrupted**

*Just forget it!*

I've got a 464 KB file I'm playing with, where I know 3 random newlines were corrupted (fewer than expected by chance, I guess I was lucky), besides the one on line 1 (in the magic number), and my estimate is that it will take 4 years to find the correct combination with the brute force approach. I'm not in business!

In this case I'm running with a 3-deep version of that brute force loop. I'm going to let it run a few days for the fun of it but I don't expect it to find anything, since I'm not willing to let it run for 4 years...

**Background**

The scripts above are based on these assumptions:

*Header*

PNG files have a magic number - an 8-byte header - which contains two newlines, one in Dos-style CRLF format, and one Unix-style LF. These exist precisely to detect corruption from newline conversion. So fixing the file will require fixing the magic number, e.g., using the solution provided by @Deniz in his answer.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

*Body*

The body of a PNG file is compressed, and therefore we can expect a high entropy random distribution of the bytes and bytes pairs in there, e.g., the uniform distribution. (That's what compression algorithms strive to achieve, after all!) So, we can expect on average 1 newline per 256 bytes, and on average 1 out of 256 of those to be a CRLF. Thus, we have on average one LF to convert back to CRLF per 64KB of a PNG file.

*pngcheck*

The program `pngcheck` (among others I'm sure) can be used to verify the validity of a PNG file, including its magic number and a checksum stored in the file. So we can use to to know when we found which LFs were originally CRLFs.

*The "right" solution*

A good solution to this problem would exploit further knowledge of the data format and make an informed decision for each newline. For example, one could analyze the two decompressed data streams resulting from considering a few dozen more bytes after each newline, assuming the newline was originally LF or CRLF, respectively. With intimate knowledge of the data format, or maybe some machine learning, this should be possible...

*The brute force solution*

Lacking deep understanding of the PNG file format, one can recover small files by brute force, trying all combinations of converting up to two random corrupted newlines back to CRLF. However, the computational cost is exponential in the number of CRLFs in the original file, so generalizing the approach beyond two corrupted random newlines is pointless.

Comment: Nice run. #joanis2023

Comment: Next challenge: use machine learning to decide yes or no on each newline without having to process the whole file this brute force way, or maybe use the png specification to decide on the validity of each yes/no decision after reading just a few more bytes. I imagine it can be done, but now I'm definitely not working on that!

Comment: @RomainValeri nice hash tag. :) Based on how far it got overnight, I might have to update it to #joanis2027... Keep on cheering!

Comment: @Ben.W yeah, you're welcome and I'm sorry. It was fun to play with this problem in any case. You never said how big your files were, but I assume bigger than my test cases?

Comment: @joanis The files are larger than 1MB. Actually there are also some JPG files to be rescued. But never mind...

Answer (score 0):

The solution made by joanis works for small files. [A blog post made by Alexander Taylor](https://fuzyll.com/2015/uncorrupting-a-png-image/) shows a solution that also works for large files. It fixes the png file block for block and is therefore fast. I have tested it with a corrupted png file of 800kb. It fixed 9 errors (as reported by the script).

The description and code below are from the blog and posted here in case the link breaks:

1. Read the corrupted PNG into memory.
2. Slice the PNG into individual chunks.
3. Determine which chunks are invalid due to CRC and/or length errors.
4. Fix each invalid chunk with a combinatoric, brute-force approach.
5. Re-assemble the uncorrupted PNG and write it to disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "zlib"

abort "Usage: #{__FILE__} <input_file> <output_file>" if ARGV.size < 1

File.open(ARGV.shift, "rb") do |input|
    File.open(ARGV.shift, "wb") do |output|
        # read file into memory
        file = input.read()
        puts "[+] Read file of size #{file.length}"

        # correct header if necessary
        if file[4] != "\r"
            file.insert(4, "\r")
        end
        output.write(file[0..7])

        # find all chunks via text search of type (finding them via size may not work due to corrruption)
        offsets = []
        ["IHDR", "PLTE", "IDAT", "IEND", "sBIT", "pHYs", "tEXt"].each do |type|
            file.scan(type) do |match|
                offsets << (Regexp.last_match.offset(0)[0] - 4)
            end
        end
        offsets.sort!
        offsets << file.length

        # attempt to fix all broken chunks
        i = 0
        while i < (offsets.length - 1) do
            # get the chunk out of the file
            chunk = file[offsets[i]..(offsets[i+1]-1)]
            size = chunk[0..3].unpack("L>")[0]  # first 4 bytes are chunk's size
            type = chunk[4..7]  # next 4 bytes are chunk's type
            crc = chunk[-4..-1].unpack("L>")[0]  # last 4 bytes are chunk's CRC

            # only process incorrect chunks
            if Zlib.crc32(chunk[4..-5]) == crc  # CRC only checks type + data
                output.write(chunk)
                i += 1
            else
                # ensure we are actually missing bytes in the chunk
                missing = size - (chunk.length - 12)
                if missing == 0
                    puts "[!] Cannot fix broken #{chunk[4..7]} chunk @ 0x#{offsets[i].to_s(16)}: No missing bytes!"
                    output.write(chunk)
                    i += 1
                    next
                elsif missing < 0
                    puts "[!] Cannot fix broken #{chunk[4..7]} chunk @ 0x#{offsets[i].to_s(16)}: Incorrect size!"
                    output.write(chunk)
                    i += 1
                    next
                else
                    puts "[*] #{chunk[4..7]} @ 0x#{offsets[i].to_s(16)} is missing #{missing} bytes"
                end

                # check all combinations of added bytes to see if we can fix the chunk
                linefeeds = []
                chunk.scan("\n") do |lf|
                    linefeeds << Regexp.last_match.offset(0)[0]
                end
                possibilities = linefeeds.combination(missing)
                if possibilities.count <= 0
                    puts "[!] Cannot fix broken #{chunk [4..7]} chunk @ 0x#{offsets[i].to_s(16)}: No valid solutions!"
                    output.write(chunk)
                    i += 1
                    next
                else
                    puts "[*] Trying all #{possibilities.count} possible ways to make CRC 0x#{crc.to_s(16)} match..."
                end

                # try and fix the chunk if it's possible
                success = false
                possibilities.each do |combo|
                    new = chunk.dup
                    offset = 0
                    combo.each do |i|
                        new.insert(i + offset, "\r")
                        offset += 1
                    end
                    if Zlib.crc32(new[4..-5]) == crc
                        puts "[+] Fixed broken #{chunk[4..7]} chunk @ 0x#{offsets[i].to_s(16)}"
                        output.write(new)
                        success = true
                        break
                    end
                end
                if not success
                    puts "[!] Cannot fix broken #{chunk [4..7]} chunk @ 0x#{offsets[i].to_s(16)}: No valid solutions!"
                    output.write(chunk)
                end
                i += 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```